# RFID f2f proximity analysis for social network

Tags: python, datetime, networking, rfid, proximity

I am looking for a way to quickly create time intervals/offset in my 40 rfid tags datasets. The chips only measure time the moment the battery is installed (the chips are from https://www.openbeacon.org/). In the experiment, 40 people had rfid chips on keycords and their interactions were recorded (each second, i no rfid chip would be around there would be no event created in the dataset but the timer will continue).

an example line from the dataset from one of the chips is as follows:

```
{ "tag_me": "0x6979EF0C", "tag_them": "0x597E5627", "time_local_s":        
2, "time_remote_s":       33, "rssi": -67, "angle": -90, "group": 1 }
```

and i would like the dataset to look like this for analysis:

```
{ "tag_me": "0x6979EF0C", "tag_them": "0x597E5627", "time_local_s":        
2, "time_remote_s":       33, "rssi": -67, "angle": -90, "group": 1, 
"cumulative_time": 20:16:02, "total_contact_time" : 4 }

{ "tag_me": "0x6979EF0C", "tag_them": "0x597E5627", "time_local_s":                
5, "time_remote_s":       36, "rssi": -66, "angle": -90, "group": 1, 
"cumulative_time": 20:16:03, "total_contact_time" : 4 }

{ "tag_me": "0x6979EF0C", "tag_them": "0x597E5627", "time_local_s":        
6, "time_remote_s":       37, "rssi": -63, "angle": -90, "group": 1, 
"cumulative_time": 20:16:04, "total_contact_time" : 4 }

{ "tag_me": "0x6979EF0C", "tag_them": "0x597E5627", "time_local_s":        
7, "time_remote_s":       38, "rssi": -57, "angle": -36, "group": 1, 
"cumulative_time": 20:16:05, "total_contact_time" : 4 }

{ "tag_me": "0x6979EF0C", "tag_them": "0x597E5627", "time_local_s":        
8, "time_remote_s":       39, "rssi": -53, "angle": -36, "group": 1, 
"cumulative_time": 20:16:06, "total_contact_time" : 4 }

{ "tag_me": "0x6979EF0C", "tag_them": "0x597E5628", "time_local_s":        
9, "time_remote_s":       40, "rssi": -53, "angle": -90, "group": 1, 
"cumulative_time": 20:16:07, "total_contact_time" : 6 }

{ "tag_me": "0x6979EF0C", "tag_them": "0x597E5628", "time_local_s":        
9, "time_remote_s":       40, "rssi": -53, "angle": -90, "group": 1, 
"cumulative_time": 20:16:07, "total_contact_time" : 6 }

{ "tag_me": "0x6979EF0C", "tag_them": "0x597E5628", "time_local_s":       
10, "time_remote_s":       41, "rssi": -54, "angle": -90, "group": 1, 
"cumulative_time": 20:16:08, "total_contact_time" : 6 }

{ "tag_me": "0x6979EF0C", "tag_them": "0x597E5628", "time_local_s":       
11, "time_remote_s":       42, "rssi": -53, "angle": -90, "group": 1, 
"cumulative_time": 20:16:09, "total_contact_time" : 6 }

{ "tag_me": "0x6979EF0C", "tag_them": "0x597E5628", "time_local_s":       
15, "time_remote_s":       44, "rssi": -53, "angle": -90, "group": 1, 
"cumulative_time": 20:16:13, "total_contact_time" : 6 }

{ "tag_me": "0x6979EF0C", "tag_them": "0x597E5629", "time_local_s":       
16, "time_remote_s":       88, "rssi": -53, "angle": -90, "group": 1, 
"cumulative_time": 20:16:14, "total_contact_time" : 1 }
```

The files are stored as a .json file. the name of the tag is "tag_me" and "tag_them" is the rfid tag the "tag_me" stumbles upon. Normally, the "cumulative_time" and "total_contact_time" are not stored in the dataset by the chips, but i added these in excel manually to show what i hope to have as end result.

My experiment started at 20:16:00, so "time_local_s" is 20:16:00 + 2 = 20:16:02. The "cumulative_time" should add the numbers from "time_local_s" to the start time of the experiment and the "total_contact_time" variable should store how long the contact lasted (for example, the contact with the first two chips lasted from 20:16:02 till 20:16:06, so 4 seconds.

Anybody knows how to achieve this result? I hope to find packages in python (perhaps pandas but i have no experience with it) that help me along, since i think that excel is not really the right tool for it (almost 9000 interactions for each chip and i have 40 of them).

i found this for now but this not helped my very much:

```
data = []
with open('timemerger.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(line)
print(data[1])

past_interactions = []
interactions = []
now = -1
new_data = []
for line in enumerate(data):
    if line["time_local_s"] > now:
        for tag_them, indices in past_interactions:
            if tag_them not in data:
                # Update new_data and remove from past_interactions
                # (Can't remove whilst iterating, so record index;
                #  remove later.)
                interactions.append(entry["tag_them"])
    # Add to past_interactions
# Unconditionally update new_data
print('    ')

print(new_data[1:4])
print(interactions)
```

------------- EDIT

i have changed the file to a csv format to make it easier for me (i have never worked with json before). It now looks like this:

```
tag_me,tag_them,time_local_s
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1356
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1360
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1361
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1362
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1363
0x597E5627,0x7DA8FFB0,1364
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1365
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1365
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1366
```

desired outcome:

```
tag_me,tag_them,time_local_s,total_time
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1356,7
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1360,7
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1361,7
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1362,7
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1363,7
0x597E5627,0x7DA8FFB0,1364,1
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1365,1
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1365,1
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1366,1
```

Answer (score 0):

To create `cumulative_time` should be easy, so I'm not going to write about it here.

`total_contact_time`, however, is hard. `tag_me` seems to always be the same, so we can ignore that. Assuming you've read each line as JSON and have converted them to a Python `dict` which you have stored in a `list`-like object which the variable `data` points to:

```
past_interactions = []
interactions = []
now = -1
new_data = [dict(entry) for entry in data]
for index, entry in enumerate(data):
    if entry["time_local_s"] > now:
        for tag_them, indices in past_interactions:
            if tag_them not in data:
                # Update new_data and remove from past_interactions
                # (Can't remove whilst iterating, so record index;
                #  remove later.)
    interactions.append(entry["tag_them"])
    # Add to past_interactions
# Unconditionally update new_data
```

I haven't finished it, since I ran out of time to work on this. This should be enough to get you started, though.

Comment: thanks for the reply! This looks great, but i get the error that list indices should be integers or slices and not str in line 14 (if data["time_local_s"] > now.

Comment: @StefanBloemheuvel You've done something really weird. Could you post the `repr` of one of the entries?

Comment: I have modified the file into a csv file to make it a bit easier for me. what do you mean with a repr?

Comment: @StefanBloemheuvel A CSV file will probably be harder to process. By `repr` I mean run the `repr` function on the object and post the output.

Comment: I've updated the code to fix the problem you were having.

Comment: i tried running the code but the interactions list is empty, no errors though

Comment: @StefanBloemheuvel It isn't complete code; you'll need to implement the bits of code that are commented.

Comment: okay i see, i will try to create some code! thanks already for all your help. i will also remove all the column's in the csv file to make it all a bit clearer for myself

Comment: @StefanBloemheuvel You should probably iterate through every (other?) line and use the `json` module, otherwise you'll have to change more of my code to make it work.

Comment: i will have to load my data in csv format into igraph though so i need to continue in csv format..

Comment: @StefanBloemheuvel Oh, ok. Just replace all instances of `entry["column_name"]` with `entry[123]` (though put the actual 0-indexed column number there).

Comment: now i already get an error at line 14 if line["time_local_s" > now: saying that typle indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @StefanBloemheuvel See my previous comment.